# Booting from custom image in GCE. Boot hang at "Booting from 0000:7c00"

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am doing a training on big data and since its based on cloudera platform I downloaded the cloudera quickstart vm for virtual box.

I don't have enough hardware to open it from my laptop so I decided to try out GCE. So I followed the instructions to convert virtual box images into RAW and then tar.gz into google GCE bucket.

Until this point, everything went fine.

I was able to crate new instance and attached a disk created out from previous instance without any issue.

After booting the instance I realized it was unresponsive, and its external IP not reachable. Looked at the serial console and found out that it shows up messages until ""Booting from 0000:7c00" and then just nothing. Seems to be a boot issue related to disk maybe...

I tried mounting this disk as a secondary one into another working instance in GCE and I was able to see its contents. So disk seems to be ok. See below some outputs from LVM commands.

```
pvs

PV         VG            Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sdb2  vg_quickstart lvm2 a--  63.51g    0

vgs

 VG            #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  vg_quickstart   1   2   0 wz--n- 63.51g    0

lvs

LV      VG            Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_root vg_quickstart -wi------- 55.51g                                                    
  lv_swap vg_quickstart -wi-------  8.00g

lvdisplay

--- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_quickstart/lv_root
  LV Name                lv_root
  VG Name                vg_quickstart
  LV UUID                DAlCfT-ALEN-ggHE-OOt5-wqn9-ejlm-30RKN1
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time quickstart.cloudera, 2015-06-09 10:04:48 +0000
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                55.51 GiB
  Current LE             14210
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_quickstart/lv_swap
  LV Name                lv_swap
  VG Name                vg_quickstart
  LV UUID                ScuNN9-IFtX-vdDd-Z4QM-sqap-2P0G-gw4ujd
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time quickstart.cloudera, 2015-06-09 10:05:03 +0000
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                8.00 GiB
  Current LE             2048
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

Below you can see the complete serial console output:

```
Changing serial settings was 0/0 now 3/0
Start bios (version 1.7.2-20150226_170051-google)
Unable to unlock ram - bridge not found
Ram Size=0xc0000000 (0x0000000030000000 high)
Relocating low data from 0x000e5810 to 0x000ef780 (size 2161)
Relocating init from 0x000e6081 to 0xbffd3540 (size 51612)
CPU Mhz=2300
=== PCI bus & bridge init ===
PCI: pci_bios_init_bus_rec bus = 0x0
=== PCI device probing ===
Found 4 PCI devices (max PCI bus is 00)
=== PCI new allocation pass #1 ===
PCI: check devices
=== PCI new allocation pass #2 ===
PCI: map device bdf=00:03.0  bar 0, addr 0000c000, size 00000040 [io]
PCI: map device bdf=00:04.0  bar 0, addr 0000c040, size 00000040 [io]
PCI: map device bdf=00:03.0  bar 1, addr febfe000, size 00001000 [mem]
PCI: map device bdf=00:04.0  bar 1, addr febff000, size 00001000 [mem]
PCI: init bdf=00:01.0 id=8086:7110
PIIX3/PIIX4 init: elcr=00 0c
PCI: init bdf=00:01.3 id=8086:7113
Using pmtimer, ioport 0xb008, freq 3579 kHz
PCI: init bdf=00:03.0 id=1af4:1004
PCI: init bdf=00:04.0 id=1af4:1000
Found 1 cpu(s) max supported 1 cpu(s)
MP table addr=0x000fdaf0 MPC table addr=0x000fdb00 size=240
SMBIOS ptr=0x000fdad0 table=0x000fd970 size=352
Memory hotplug not enabled. [MHPE=0xffffffff]
ACPI DSDT=0xbfffe070
ACPI tables: RSDP=0x000fd940 RSDT=0xbfffe030
Scan for VGA option rom
Machine UUID 99d5a402-078d-aa7b-e703-5927bca16259
Found 4 serial ports
found virtio-scsi at 0:3
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@0,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@1,0
virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0
virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=134217728
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@2,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@3,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@4,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@5,0
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@6,0
...
Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@253,0
KBD: int09 handler: AL=0
PS2 keyboard initialized
All threads complete.
Scan for option roms
Searching bootorder for: HALT
drive 0x000fd900: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=134217728
Space available for UMB: 000c0000-000eb800
Returned 122880 bytes of ZoneHigh
e820 map has 7 items:
  0: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009fc00 = 1 RAM
  1: 000000000009fc00 - 00000000000a0000 = 2 RESERVED
  2: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 = 2 RESERVED
  3: 0000000000100000 - 00000000bfffe000 = 1 RAM
  4: 00000000bfffe000 - 00000000c0000000 = 2 RESERVED
  5: 00000000fffbc000 - 0000000100000000 = 2 RESERVED
  6: 0000000100000000 - 0000000130000000 = 1 RAM
Unable to lock ram - bridge not found
KBD: int09 handler: AL=0
enter handle_19:
  NULL
Booting from Hard Disk 0...
Booting from 0000:7c00
```

What is going wrong with this VM? Thanks!

Comment: Which tutorial did you follow? This video [1] should be useful and this link [2] lists all the GCE requirements for an image to run.

[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlcR6ZLebTM
[2]: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/building-images

Comment: After some back and forth I was able to make it boot. Apparently, GCE cannot boot from boot partitions and they need only one root partition with /boot directory.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

The disk must include only one partition (root) with boot directory in it instead of a boot partition as I had before.

I am not 100% sure but probably GCE has problems booting from logical volumes (lv). Should avoid that by building a new partition and dd data from he lv root partition into the standard ext partition.

Comment: Similar problem i got even i use only root partition with "boot" inside. http://serverfault.com/questions/750143/create-centos-7-minimal-image-for-google-compute-engine?noredirect=1#comment944667_750143